# How can I factory reset my Android TV?

Tags: factory-reset, android-tv

Is there any way to do a factory reset somehow from the welcome screen as I can go through to do anything?

After prompting me to choose the language it keeps returning to the Welcome page to start over. Yes I tried every possible combination (wifi, cable, buttons, etc) but there is no way to go through so maybe a factory reset will do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Try going to `Settings --> Privacy --> Factory Data Reset`

For More Detail You can check Here:

[www.allview.ro/uploads/tx_allview/Manual_AllDro_TV.pdf](http://www.allview.ro/uploads/tx_allview/Manual_AllDro_TV.pdf)

[image]

Comment: I think I mentioned that I can't get pass the welcome screen..